# Get Python Version from Remote Host with paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

I'm writting a Software to get some Information about Server
and i just want to get the python Version from an remote Server.

Here is my code:

```
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(self.server, username=self.user, password=self.pass)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("/usr/bin/python -V")
stdin.flush()
data = stdout.readlines()
print data  #just debug
ssh.close()
```

The print just returns "[]".

Comment: side note, Fabric (http://docs.fabfile.org) wraps up Paramiko nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in stderr. Don't ask me why:

```
>>> import paramiko
>>> ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
>>> ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
>>> ssh.connect('tek')
>>> stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('python --version')
>>> stdin.flush()
>>> data = stdout.readlines()
>>> data
[]
>>> data = stderr.readlines()
>>> data
['Python 2.6.6\n']
```

Comment: I told you not to ask me that! :^)  seriously, it's probably just what Guido decided was appropriate. going to sleep now, hopefully any other questions will be answered by others.

Comment: Link to another SO question: [Why does python print version info to stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26028416/why-does-python-print-version-info-to-stderr)