# Why does python print version info to stderr?

Tags: python

Why did Guido (or whoever else) decide to make `python --version` print to stderr rather than stdout? Just curious what the use case is that makes standard error more appropriate than standard out.

Comment: it prints to stdout on python 3.4

Comment: its stderr in 3.2.3... we're narrowing it down!

Comment: the behavior was changed by [this patch](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/e6384b8b2325) and was then added to 3.4 [release notes](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/fc089cf0cf32). original [bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue18338)

Comment: I dumped help to stderr back in the day. It was considered a friendly way to let your output be piped to other programs while still dumping help if a parameter was incorrect. Consumers down the pipeline didn't need to worry about their scanners/parsers getting messed up by unexpected text. Version numbers are help also, so it goes to stderr.

Comment: It's stderr in 3.3 too.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Python 3.4 was modified to output to `stdout`, which is the expected behavior. This is listed as a bug with Python here: http://bugs.python.org/issue18338. The comments on the bug report indicate that while `stdout` is the reasonable choice, it would break backward compatibility. Python 2.7.9 is largely unchanged, because so much relies on it.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

Many programs would just use `stdout` and not care but I would prefer `stderr` on principle. In short, I believe `stdout` is for the product of successful execution of a program while `stderr` is for any messages meant for the user. Calculated values go to `stdout` while errors, stack traces, help, **version** and usage messages are meant for the user and should go to `stderr`.

I use this question to decide which to output stream is appropriate: Is this message meant for the consumer of the main product of this program (whether that's the human user or another program or whatever) or is it strictly for the human user of this program?

Also, looks like Java uses stderr for version messages as well by the way: [Why does 'java -version' go to stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483443/why-does-java-version-go-to-stderr])

Comment: I would say that in the case of `python --version` the version string is "the product of successful execution of the program".

Comment: Thanks for the effective differentiation in between ***stdout*** & ***stderr*** @Aaron.